# No proper answer from MCU while uploading lua script onto Feather Huzzah ESP8266

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a Adafruit Feather Huzzah ESP8266 and want to load a lua script onto it.

The script is out of [this Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/manually-bridging-mqtt-mosquitto-to-adafruit-io/programming-the-esp8266) and I changed only the Wifi and MQTT connection settings.

I followed the instructions at 
https://github.com/4refr0nt/luatool#run
and used the following command:

```
python ./luatool.py --port /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART --src LightSensor-master/init.lua --dest init.lua --verbose
```

I get the following error

```
Upload starting
Stage 1. Deleting old file from flash memory
->file.open("init.lua", "w")Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./luatool.py", line 272, in <module>
    transport.writeln("file.open(\"" + args.dest + "\", \"w\")\r")
  File "./luatool.py", line 111, in writeln
    self.performcheck(data)
  File "./luatool.py", line 61, in performcheck
    raise Exception('No proper answer from MCU')
Exception: No proper answer from MCU
```

What is the error here, what am I doing wrong?

I tried flashing the nodemcu dev version to the Feather. This didn't change the problem. I also read some advice to stabilize the power supply and added a battery to the feather–-also without success.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a delay of 0.6 ms to the `luatool.py` solved the problem for me:

```
python ./luatool.py --delay 0.6 --port /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART --src LightSensor-master/init.lua --dest init.lua --verbose
```

I found this solution because I read some advice that the python script might try to talk to the Feather faster than the Feather can answer.

Comment: in above it was not mentioned with restart which I think causes hand sometimes @nnn

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I detached the cable and attached again and ran the command

```
sudo python esp8266/luatool.py --delay 0.6 --port /dev/ttyUSB0 --src init.lua --dest init.lua --restart  --verbose
```

1st time it fails but next time execute the same command and it works for me.